# PHP 7.4 CI 3 short echo tag throw exception while loading CI view

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, shorthand

```
<?= $this->load->view('test_view.php', []); ?>
```

Above load view is working fine till PHP 7.3 but after upgrading to PHP 7.4, it throws exception **Object of class MY_Loader could not be converted to string**.

It make sense, its a shorthand for echo not object but curiosity is why it was working in PHP 7.3 ?

Comment: use `<?=$this->load->view('test_view', '', TRUE);?>`

Comment: yes, i am using this, but i didnt see the documentation that why it behave different with 7.4